# pattern for implementing undo/redo in clojure

Tags: design-patterns, clojure, functional-programming

Is there an established pattern for implementing undo/redo functionality in clojure or in fp in general?

In an OO language I would go with the command pattern but as it is all about state I wonder if it is idiomatic doing it in clojure.

Are there any libraries that could be of help?

Comment: A preceding question should be whether or not you actually need this state mutation in the first place.

Comment: @Alex Taggart: and of course you really don't (but I take it that was your point ; )  I've written undo/redo using only immutable objects (in Java).  You can write an undo/redo by only saving (user inputs) and by recreating your "state" by replaying your inputs up to the desired time.  So when you want to undo from "t5 to t4" you do not "rewind" from t5 to t4, but you replay the inputs from t0 to t4 (and because you're doing it in a "functional way", you're guaranteed to end up with the correct state).  Works in a lot of cases and greatly simplifies implementing undo/redo IMHO...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As with many design patterns you can implement this one as a function in clojure. It depends a little on how you represent state in your program (refs, atoms, agents) through the process is very similar.

You sould simply **add a watcher function to your state** agent/ref/atom that adds the state to the undo list every time there is an update. then your undo function is just looks it up in the undo list. This has the nice effect of adding your unto to the undo list, allowing for redo as well

My first impression is that `ref`s may be the correct tool for this because you will be able to restore them all in a coordinated fashion, unless of course you can reduce your programs state down to a single identity (in the Clojure sense of the word) then you would not need coordinated update and an agent would work.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like a nice solution. But to see if I get this right: I have 3 refs representing my state. i call add-watch on each of them. When some or all of them get changed in a transaction, the watcher takes a snapshot of all of them and put it on a stack. The undo function would open a new transaction and restore the last snapshot state in all of my refs.

Comment: Yes. I suppose something needs to ensure that the three watchers don't add the same state to the stack three times as well.

Comment: right. I could as well live with aggregating all state information into one single atom. This would make the transitions a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I made it work like Arthur Ulfeldt suggested:

```
(defn cmd-stack [state-ref]
  (let [stack (atom ['() '()])]
    (add-watch state-ref :cmdhistory
           (fn [key ref old new]
             (let [redo-stack '()
                   undo-stack (conj (second @stack) old)]
             (reset! stack [redo-stack undo-stack]))))
    stack))

(defn can-redo? [stack]
  (not (empty? (first @stack))))

(defn can-undo? [stack]
  (not (empty? (second @stack))))

(defn undo! [stack state-ref]
  (let [redo-stack (first @stack)
        undo-stack (second @stack)
        current-state @state-ref
        last-state (first undo-stack)]
    (assert (can-undo? stack) "cannot undo")
    (reset! state-ref last-state)
    (reset! stack [(conj redo-stack current-state) (drop 1 undo-stack)])))

(defn redo! [stack state-ref]
  (let [redo-stack (first @stack)
        undo-stack (second @stack)
        current-state @state-ref
        last-state (first redo-stack)]
    (assert (can-redo? stack) "cannot redo")
    (reset! state-ref last-state)
    (reset! stack [(drop 1 redo-stack) (conj undo-stack current-state)])))
```

But what I still don't quite understand is why. Since the undo! and redo! functions update the atom that is being watched, shouldn't the watcher react to that and thus mess up the command stack by putting the undone value back on it?

Comment: The question of undoing an undo requires thinking. Do you want two consecutive undos to be equivalent to undo and then redo?

Comment: this answer may be better represented as an edit to the original question.

Comment: @Arthur: first question: no, I would of course not expect such a behaviour. That wasn't what I meant. I meant, that I would have expected the above code to be wrong (like you describe) but it actually behaves correctly. At least according to the unit tests ;-). Your Second comment: I was thinking that too first, but then found, that the post is actually an answer to my original question, only one which raises another question.

Comment: It might be helpful to think of your changes as a succession of states from left (older) to right (newer). Then think of hitting undo as going left, and redo as going right. Then the only question is what happens if you aren't at the rightmost state, and you make a change. I'd suggest that if you can, you compare the current change to the next state to the right. If it's identical, just move along one state. If not, then push the new state to be the most recent left state, and destroy all states to the right.

Comment: P.s. sorry if your code already does this, but for me Clojure is still a write-only language :)